# Hidding all the buttons from a calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a button that makes all the buttons on the calculator disappear, when I click, it shows and hides those buttons

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>.:: Calculadora Janson ::.</title>
<style>

#botao {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 color: #ffffff;
 padding: 10px 30px;
 cursor:pointer;

 background-color:#66CCFF;
 width:40px;
 font-weight:bold;
 border:1px solid #333333;

 background: -moz-linear-gradient(
  top,
  #fa0004 0%,
  #fa0004 45%,
  #fa0004);

 background: -webkit-gradient(
  linear, left top, left bottom,
  from(#fa0004),
  color-stop(0.45, #fa0004),
  to(#fa0004));


 -moz-border-radius: 5px;
 -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
 border-radius: 5px;
 border: 1px solid #fa0004;
 -moz-box-shadow:
  0px 1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
  inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 -webkit-box-shadow:
  0px 1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
  inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 box-shadow:
  0px 1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.2),
  inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0.7);
 text-shadow:
  0px -1px 0px rgba(000,000,000,0.3),
  0px 0px 0px rgba(255,255,255,0);
}





}

.text {
 width:100px;
 text-align:right;
 background-color:#D9EEF9;
 font-weight:bold;
}
.style1 {
 font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-size: 14px;
 font-weight: bold;
}

#ajuda {
 width:400px;
 height:300px;
 margin:0 auto;
 font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:12px;
}
</style>

<script>
 
 function calc(valor) {
  
  s = document.getElementById('res').value;
  document.getElementById('res').value = s + valor;
 }
 
 function sinal(oper) {
  si = document.getElementById('res').value;
  document.getElementById('res').value = si + oper + " ";
 }
 
 function calcula() {
  vet = document.getElementById('res').value;
  vet2 = vet.split(' ');
  switch(vet2[1]) {
   case 'X':
    resultado = vet2[0] * vet2[2];
    break;
   case '÷':
    resultado = vet2[0] / vet2[2];
    break;
   case '+':
    resultado = parseFloat(vet2[0]) + parseFloat(vet2[2]);
    break;
   case '-':
    resultado = vet2[0] - vet2[2];
    break;
   case "v":
    resultado = Math.sqrt(vet2[0]);
    break;
   case 'Log':
    resultado = Math.LOG10E*Math.log(vet2[0]);
    break;
   case '^':
    resultado = Math.pow(vet2[0], vet2[2]);
    break;

  }
  document.getElementById('res').value = resultado;
  return true;
 }
 
 function limpa() {
  document.getElementById('res').value = "";
 }


 function limpaBotoes() {
  document.getElementById('res').value = "";
 }
 
 function porcento() {
  vet = document.getElementById('res').value;
  vet2 = vet.split(' ');
  if(vet2[1] == 'X')
   document.getElementById('res').value = (vet2[0] * vet2[2])/100;
  else if(vet2[1] == '+')
   document.getElementById('res').value = parseFloat((vet2[0] * vet2[2])/100) + parseFloat(vet2[0]);
  else if(vet2[1] == '-')
   document.getElementById('res').value = parseFloat(vet2[0]) - parseFloat((vet2[0] * vet2[2])/100);
 }

 // função apenas para gerar o help da calculadora
 function help() {
  document.getElementById('ajuda').innerHTML = "<u>Para as operações básicas usa-se da seguinte forma:</u> <br>"  
          + "     Ex: 3 + 2 = 5 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 3 - 2 = 1 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 3 x 2 = 6 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 3 ÷ 2 = 1.5 <br>"
          + "<u>Para operações de porcentagem:</u><br>"
          + "     Ex: 25 x 10 % = 2.5 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 25 + 10 % = 27.5 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 25 - 10 % = 22.5 <br>"
          + "<u>Para logaritmo:</u> <br>"
          + "     Ex: 2 log = 0.3010...<br>"
          + "<u>Para raiz quadrada:</u> <br>"
          + "     Ex: 16 √¯ = 4 <br>"
          + "<u>Potenciação:</u> <br>"
          + "     Ex: 2 x² 2 = 4 <br>"
          + "     Ex: 2 x³ 3 = 8 <br><br>"
          + "<u>OBS: Essa versão ainda não calcula expressão linear como nos ex:</u> <br>"
          + "     3 + 5 + 2 x 2 <br>"
          + "     4 + 2 - 7 ÷ 2";
               
  setTimeout("limpaajuda()",15000);
 }
 function limpaajuda() {
  document.getElementById('ajuda').innerHTML = "";
 }


// the fuction to hide the buttons 
var hidden = false;
function action()
{
    function action() {
        hidden = !hidden;
        if(hidden) {
            document.getElementById('botao').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('botao').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

}


</script>


</head>

<body>

<table width="203" height="269" border="9" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td><table width="186" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
          <td width="97"><span class="style1">Quelipe</span></td>
          <td width="89" class="style1"></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr valign="top">
    <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><br />
      <table width="159" border="0" align="center">
      <tr>
        <td height="33" colspan="4"><label><input name="res" type="text" id="res" size="20" class="text" disabled="disabled"/></label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="button" name="button15" value="%" id="botao" onclick="porcento()"/></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="button" name="button17" value="√¯" id="botao" onclick="sinal(' v');"/></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="button" name="button18" value="Log" id="botao" onclick="sinal(' Log');"/></label></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button19" value="X²" onclick="sinal(' ^');" id="botao" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="38"><label><input type="button" name="button" value="7" onclick="calc('7');" id="botao" accesskey="7"/></label></td>
        <td width="36"><input type="button" name="button2" value="8" onclick="calc('8');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td width="36"><input type="button" name="button3" value="9" onclick="calc('9');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td width="24"><input type="button" name="button4" value="÷" onclick="sinal(' ÷');" id="botao"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="button5" value="4" onclick="calc('4');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button6" value="5" onclick="calc('5');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button7" value="6" onclick="calc('6');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button8" value="x" onclick="sinal(' X');" id="botao"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" name="button9" value="1" onclick="calc('1');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button10" value="2" onclick="calc('2');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button11" value="3" onclick="calc('3');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button16" value="- " onclick="sinal(' -');" id="botao"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><label><input type="button" name="button13" value="CE" onclick="limpa()" id="botao"/></label></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button14" value="0" onclick="calc('0');" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="submit" name="Submit162" value="=" onclick="calcula()" id="botao"/></td>
        <td><input type="button" name="button12" value="+" onclick="sinal(' +');" id="botao"/></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> </td>
        <td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="." id="botao" onclick="calc('.');"/></label></td>
        <td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Help" id="botao" onclick="help();"/></label></td>
        <td> </td>
      </tr>
    </table>

 </td>
  </tr>
</table>


<input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="action();" />
<p> </p>
<div id="ajuda">
 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i was trying to hide eveything with the "function action()" using the buttons id, but nothing changes

Comment: You have repeated the code in the function `action` just remove the inner function (repetition) and it should work!

Comment: IDs should be unique by the way!

Comment: You have multiple elements with the same id.  Id's are unique.  give all the buttons the same class and hide that class when you click the hide button.

Comment: @Derek can you show me a example? just starting with html

Answer (score 1):

Replace all the id numbers attached to the button with a class attribute of the same value.An id number is a number assigned to a unique element

Declare one action function and not a nested function with a duplicated `action()`

Instead of adding a variable hidden and testing that variable. You can add a toggle effect which add or remove a css class. This class will change the opacity:0.

If the toggle() method returns true simply disable the button. You can use display:none. Nevertheless with this property, the dimension of calculator will change since the elements will not be in the dom when hidden.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
  <title>.:: Calculadora Janson ::.</title>
  <style>
  .botao {
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      color: #ffffff;
      padding: 10px 30px;
      cursor: pointer;
      background-color: #66CCFF;
      width: 40px;
      font-weight: bold;
      border: 1px solid #333333;
      background: -moz-linear-gradient( top, #fa0004 0%, #fa0004 45%, #fa0004);
      background: -webkit-gradient( linear, left top, left bottom, from(#fa0004), color-stop(0.45, #fa0004), to(#fa0004));
      -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
      border: 1px solid #fa0004;
      -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.2), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.2), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.2), inset 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
      text-shadow: 0px -1px 0px rgba(000, 000, 000, 0.3), 0px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    }
    
    .hide {
      opacity: 0;
    }
  }
  .text {
    width: 100px;
    text-align: right;
    background-color: #D9EEF9;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  .style1 {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
  #ajuda {
    width: 400px;
    height: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
  }
  </style>

  <script>
    function calc(valor) {

      s = document.getElementById('res').value;
      document.getElementById('res').value = s + valor;
    }

    function sinal(oper) {
      si = document.getElementById('res').value;
      document.getElementById('res').value = si + oper + " ";
    }

    function calcula() {
      vet = document.getElementById('res').value;
      vet2 = vet.split(' ');
      switch (vet2[1]) {
        case 'X':
          resultado = vet2[0] * vet2[2];
          break;
        case '÷':
          resultado = vet2[0] / vet2[2];
          break;
        case '+':
          resultado = parseFloat(vet2[0]) + parseFloat(vet2[2]);
          break;
        case '-':
          resultado = vet2[0] - vet2[2];
          break;
        case "v":
          resultado = Math.sqrt(vet2[0]);
          break;
        case 'Log':
          resultado = Math.LOG10E * Math.log(vet2[0]);
          break;
        case '^':
          resultado = Math.pow(vet2[0], vet2[2]);
          break;

      }
      document.getElementById('res').value = resultado;
      return true;
    }

    function limpa() {
      document.getElementById('res').value = "";
    }


    function limpaBotoes() {
      document.getElementById('res').value = "";
    }

    function porcento() {
      vet = document.getElementById('res').value;
      vet2 = vet.split(' ');
      if (vet2[1] == 'X')
        document.getElementById('res').value = (vet2[0] * vet2[2]) / 100;
      else if (vet2[1] == '+')
        document.getElementById('res').value = parseFloat((vet2[0] * vet2[2]) / 100) + parseFloat(vet2[0]);
      else if (vet2[1] == '-')
        document.getElementById('res').value = parseFloat(vet2[0]) - parseFloat((vet2[0] * vet2[2]) / 100);
    }

    // função apenas para gerar o help da calculadora
    function help() {
      document.getElementById('ajuda').innerHTML = "<u>Para as operações básicas usa-se da seguinte forma:</u> <br>" +
        "     Ex: 3 + 2 = 5 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 3 - 2 = 1 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 3 x 2 = 6 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 3 ÷ 2 = 1.5 <br>" +
        "<u>Para operações de porcentagem:</u><br>" +
        "     Ex: 25 x 10 % = 2.5 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 25 + 10 % = 27.5 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 25 - 10 % = 22.5 <br>" +
        "<u>Para logaritmo:</u> <br>" +
        "     Ex: 2 log = 0.3010...<br>" +
        "<u>Para raiz quadrada:</u> <br>" +
        "     Ex: 16 √¯ = 4 <br>" +
        "<u>Potenciação:</u> <br>" +
        "     Ex: 2 x² 2 = 4 <br>" +
        "     Ex: 2 x³ 3 = 8 <br><br>" +
        "<u>OBS: Essa versão ainda não calcula expressão linear como nos ex:</u> <br>" +
        "     3 + 5 + 2 x 2 <br>" +
        "     4 + 2 - 7 ÷ 2";

      setTimeout("limpaajuda()", 15000);
    }

    function limpaajuda() {
      document.getElementById('ajuda').innerHTML = "";
    }

    function action() {
      var all_btn = document.getElementsByClassName('botao');
      for (var x = 0; x < all_btn.length; ++x) {
        all_btn[x].classList.toggle('hide') ? all_btn[x].disabled = true : all_btn[x].disabled = false;
      }

    }
  </script>


</head>

<body>

  <table width="203" height="269" border="9" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table width="186" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
          <tr>
            <td width="97"><span class="style1">Quelipe</span></td>
            <td width="89" class="style1"></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr valign="top">
      <td bgcolor="#EFEFEF"><br />
        <table width="159" border="0" align="center">
          <tr>
            <td height="33" colspan="4"><label><input name="res" type="text" id="res" size="20" class="text" disabled="disabled"/></label></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label><input type="button" name="button15" value="%" class="botao" onclick="porcento()"/></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="button" name="button17" value="√¯" class="botao" onclick="sinal(' v');"/></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="button" name="button18" value="Log" class="botao" onclick="sinal(' Log');"/></label></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button19" value="X²" onclick="sinal(' ^');" class="botao" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td width="38"><label><input type="button" name="button" value="7" onclick="calc('7');" class="botao" accesskey="7"/></label></td>
            <td width="36"><input type="button" name="button2" value="8" onclick="calc('8');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td width="36"><input type="button" name="button3" value="9" onclick="calc('9');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td width="24"><input type="button" name="button4" value="÷" onclick="sinal(' ÷');" class="botao" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="button5" value="4" onclick="calc('4');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button6" value="5" onclick="calc('5');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button7" value="6" onclick="calc('6');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button8" value="x" onclick="sinal(' X');" class="botao" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><input type="button" name="button9" value="1" onclick="calc('1');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button10" value="2" onclick="calc('2');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button11" value="3" onclick="calc('3');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button16" value="- " onclick="sinal(' -');" class="botao" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td><label><input type="button" name="button13" value="CE" onclick="limpa()" class="botao"/></label></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button14" value="0" onclick="calc('0');" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="Submit162" value="=" onclick="calcula()" class="botao" /></td>
            <td><input type="button" name="button12" value="+" onclick="sinal(' +');" class="botao" /></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td> </td>
            <td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="." class="botao" onclick="calc('.');"/></label></td>
            <td><label><input type="submit" name="Submit2" value="Help" class="botao" onclick="help();"/></label></td>
            <td> </td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>


  <input type="button" id="toggler" value="Toggler" onClick="action();" />
  <p> </p>
  <div id="ajuda">

  </div>
</body>

</html>
```